# Convex Optimization problem labeled as non convex

Tags: python-3.x, convex-optimization, cvxopt, cvxpy

I'm using cvxpy (1.0.11) to solve a convex optimization problem.

The convex problem I have is being labelled as non-convex I think because it does not know that the parameter `alpha` is bounded between [0, 1].

I know this from this line fails...
`loss = mse + (1-alpha) * lam * (penalty_1 + penalty_2) + alpha * lam * penalty_3`

while this line succeeds...
`loss = mse + lam * (penalty_1 + penalty_2) + lam * penalty_3`

Right now the hyperparameters are parameterized this way. If there is a way to bound them I haven't found it in anywhere in the API

```
alpha = cvx.Parameter(nonneg=True)
alpha.value = 0.5
lam = cvx.Parameter(nonneg=True)
lam.value = 10**(2)
```

How do I tell `cvxpy` that alpha is a number between [0, 1]?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that, I would create another parameter for `1-alpha` and make it `nonneg` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that that is trivially simple. Instead of setting alpha as a parameter simply set it as a normal float.

```
alpha = 0.5
lam = cvx.Paramter(nonneg=True)
lam.value = 1e2
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but you lose the benefits of parameters. You need to reconstruct the problem for each alpha now. https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html?highlight=parameter#parameters

Comment: Yes, I do. But since alpha is held constant for any given problem this isn't an issue.